# Open bank account in the US or Canada

Tags: bank-account, online-banking

I don't know this is the right place to place this type of question or not. I am an indian citizen and I have an Indian passport. But i want to open a bank account in the US or Canada. Is there any way to open an account if I never visited these countries before and don't want to visit to create a bank account either? I want to use that account to receive money and transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will almost certainly find it much easier to open an account in India with a bank that also operates in North America, and they should provide services that will meet any legitimate need that you have for a US bank account.